# Is there a way to remove a specific value from an attribute using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that displays products. In the encompassing `<ul>` I have some jQuery that adds values to attributes (such as `<ul id="products" subcategorynavids="someValue">`).

When a user clicks a filtering link, the jQuery checks the contents of `subcategorynavids` and then only displays products below that have a navid that is listed.

What I'm having an issue with is when the attribute has more than one value listed, and the user clicks the filter link a second time (to disable it), I need to remove ONLY the value that is being disabled...

For example, if the page is set to `<ul id="products" subcategorynavids="9007 8019 7365">` and the user clicks the filter that enables/disables `navid="8019"`, how do I remove the '8019' and leave the '9007' and '7365'?

I know there is `.removeAttr()`, `.removeProp()`, but those only remove the attribute ENTIRELY (right?).

I tried the following (which, as expected, didn't work)...

```
$("#products").attr('subcategorynavids').remove('8019');
```

Comment: Use `data-` attributes for your custom HTML attributes so that they're forward compatible with HTML5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in jQuery way to do this, you'll have to do it manually.

```
$('#products').attr('subcategorynavids', function (_, val) {
    return jQuery.grep(val.split(' '), function (val) {
        return val !== '8019';
    }).join(' ');
});
```

Here we use the callback way of using [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) to update an attribute. Inside the function, we split the current value `val` by `' '`, and then filter the resulting array for those that aren't `8019` using [jQuery's`grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep) function*, and the join the array back together and return it to be the new value of `subcategorynavids`.

* I'd want  to use `Array`'s `filter()` method, but it's not supported in all modern browsers, so you might as well use `grep()`.

Comment: Remember that with jQuery iterator callbacks, you need to think backwards WRT parameters. The `idx` param comes first... unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you could just use `.replace()`

```
var $attrs = $("#products").attr('subcategorynavids');
$("#products").attr( 'subcategorynavids', $attrs.replace( '8019', '' ));
```

Comment: This worked great! Just concerned after @Matt pointed out that some undesired actions could occur. But I think with the four digit id's that I'm using, this method will work just fine :) Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! The easy solution to @Matt's problem would be to pad the IDs with some spaces, then wrap the value in your replace function. e.g. `subcategorynavids=" 9007 8019 7365 "`, then in your replace: `.replace( ' 8019 ', ' ' );`. Now we can be sure no other IDs are affected! :)

Answer (score 0):

> use .replace()

```
$("#products").attr('subcategorynavids',$("#products").attr('subcategorynavids').replace('8019 ',''));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/laupkram/fg3dn/

Comment: you're welcome but its really short and straight, is this the only thing you need?

Comment: @derekmx271: Just be aware of having IDs which contain other IDs with this approach. If you had `subcategorynavids="12 1"` and you tried to remove `1`, you'd be left with `subcategorynavids="2 1"` (as `replace()` only replaces the first instance by default).

Comment: @Mahan: `subcategorynavids="12 3 2"` and now try remove `2` ;) (will have `subcategorynavids="13 2"`)

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
var attr = $("#products").attr('subcategorynavids');
$("#products").attr('subcategorynavids', attr.replace('8019',''));
```

First get the values in that attribute and filter out the key word and again set the new attribute.. simple as that

Comment: You don't need `.indexOf()`. Just do the `.replace()`, and if there's no match, there'll be no change. Also, you need to store the result of `.replace()` because strings are immutable.